# Integration between ELK and LDAP

Tags: elasticsearch, ldap, kibana

I recently got to manage an opensource-based infrastructure composed by multiple Debian servers. On some of them, the ELK stack is installed.
I am verifying verify the presence of any integration between ELK and LDAP or other IAMs. On the dedicated monitoring node, I looked for IAM-related info into the following configuration files:

> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml
>
> /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
>
> /etc/logstash/logstash.yml

but the only login/account credentials I have been able to find are in the kibana.yml file:

```
elasticsearch.username: "username"
elasticsearch.password: "password"
```

In */etc/kibana/kibana.yml* and */etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml*  I find the following:

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

which leads me think to the presence of a "xpack" plugin in somehow related to ldap. Where should I look for LDAP integration ?

Comment: If security is disabled then there is no authentication on elasticsearch, also to have a integration with LDAP you need a paid license and configure it in elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: On logstash you have to set credentials on output

Comment: @leandrojmp thats not true, if he use some plugin for security. Im using ReadOnlyRest and have to  disable xpack security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wonka for suggesting the presence of ReadOnlyRest. I found a *readonlyrest.yml* in /etc/elasticsearch. There, the following was present:

```
ldaps:
- name: ldap1
host: "ourldapserver.ourdomain"
[...]
```

Here is where LDAP integration occured.